# How to update and post in single operation in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

```
    var postStop = async (machine,stop_name,timestamp)=>{
        var stop = new Stop({
            machine_name:machine,
            stop_name:stop_name,
            start_time:timestamp,
            end_time:null
        });
        stop.save();
}
    var updateStop = async (machine,stop_name,start_time,end_time)=>{ 
    var stop = await Stop.findOne({machine_name:machine,stop_name:stop_name,start_time:start_time});
    if(!stop){
        console.log(machine,stop_name,start_time,end_time)
    }
    stop.end_time = end_time;
    stop.save();
}
```

I have to update and post in a single operation with some condition.
I have combined this two into single how to do this .

Answer (score 0):

If You are looking to update or create in the same action you can use [upsert option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-upsert)

```
var stop = await Stop.update(
    {machine_name:machine,stop_name:stop_name,start_time:start_time},
    {end_time:end_time},
    {upsert: true});
```

Comment: thank you for your response, actually, I'm creating a time interval series databases where every document has start_time and end_time and for every new document insert firstly I have to update last inserted value end_timestamp and this timestamp is the start_time for next inserted documen

Answer (score 0):

There is option to insert document (if not present) and update (if present) in single query.

Syntax:
db.collection.update(query, update, {upsert: true})

Comment: thank you for your response, actually, I'm creating a time interval series databases where every document has start_time and end_time and for every new document insert firstly I have to update last inserted value end_timestamp and this timestamp is the start_time for next inserted document